# Calculate total time of a value being bigger than X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that contains dates, time and temperature. I'm trying to find a way to easily get a short version of the table that will give me the date and total time if the temperature was higher than 6.5 (for example).

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And what if you have only single occurences of the temperature, going above 6.5?

Answer (score 0):

i got it somewhat right, but without the total time it was over the temperature.

i did helper cell in C1 (over what temperature you want to show on table)
then on A2 i putted

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E$2:E12;SMALL(IF(G$2:G12>C$1;ROW(E$2:E12)-MIN(ROW(E$2:E12))+1);ROWS($A$2:A2)));"")
```

Insert as Array formula CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, then you can drag it downwards as far as you would like
On column B (B2)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F$2:F12;SMALL(IF(G$2:G12>C$1;ROW(F$2:F12)-MIN(ROW(F$2:F12))+1);ROWS($B$2:B2)));"")
```

also inster as array CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

should look something like this
[image]

just fiddle with the range as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with offset arrays, to find the time where the temperature in the original array (G2:G14) is <=6.5 and the temperature in the shifted array (G3:G15) is >6.5, then subtract it from the time when the temperature in the original array is >6.5 and the temperature in the shifted array is <=6.5.

```
=INDEX(F2:F14,MATCH(1,(G2:G14>6.5)*(G3:G15<=6.5),0))-INDEX(F3:F15,MATCH(1,(G2:G14<=6.5)*(G3:G15>6.5),0))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Non-array version:

```
=INDEX(F2:F14,MATCH(1,INDEX((G2:G14>6.5)*(G3:G15<=6.5),0),0))-INDEX(F3:F15,MATCH(1,INDEX((G2:G14<=6.5)*(G3:G15>6.5),0),0))
```

But @Dominique is right, if there was only one point above 6.5 degrees you could argue that the time spent above 6.5 rather than being zero was at least 10 and possibly 20 minutes, because of the 10 minute spacing of the time points and the fact that the temperature seems to be uniformly increasing then decreasing.

```
=INDEX(E3:E15,MATCH(1,(G2:G14<=6.5)*(G3:G15>6.5),0))
```

or

```
=INDEX(E3:E15,MATCH(1,INDEX((G2:G14<=6.5)*(G3:G15>6.5),0),0))
```

for the date.

[image]